# Получить XPath'ы

Tags: xml, sql-server, xpath

Допустим, в БД имеется колонка типа XML, где описана некоторая структура.

Например:

```
<root>
<TableRow>
<field></field>
</TableRow>
</root>
```

Как я могу из этого получить дерево в виде таблицы вида:

```
Node|
    root
    root/TableRow
    root/TableRow/field
```

?

Структура может меняться.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Используйте рекурсивный `CTE` запрос:

```
DECLARE @xml XML = 
'<root>
<TableRow>
<field>45r</field>
</TableRow>
<TableRow>
<field>1</field>
<field2>1</field2>
</TableRow>
</root>';

WITH x ([Node], SubNode) AS
   (
      SELECT
         [Node]      = t.n.value('local-name(.)', 'nvarchar(max)'),
         [SubNode]   = t.n.query('*')
      FROM @xml.nodes('*') AS t(n)

      UNION ALL

      SELECT
         [Node]      = x.[Node] + N'/' + t.n.value('local-name(.)', 'nvarchar(max)'),
         [SubNode]   = t.n.query('*')
      FROM x
      CROSS APPLY x.SubNode.nodes('*') AS t(n)
   )
SELECT DISTINCT
   x.[Node]
FROM x;
```