# Как в MS SQL можно сравнить структурно сравнить XML между собой?

Tags: sql-server, xml

Допустим, есть XML A и XML B.

Какие способы есть получить список отличных XPATH'ов между ними?

Comment: Есть способы получения таблиц из XML, можно преобразовать оба в таблицу, и из одной таблицы "вычесть" другую. В таблицу можно преобразовать ветвь/подветвь с группой ветвей.

Comment: @nick_n_a если есть вложенность, то каждый узел, который внутри себя содержит группу узлов будет таблицей, по идее... А это гемор.

Comment: По идее можно вообще "взорвать XML" - т.е. привести его к виду id, parent_id, value. Но боюсь.... что в общем случае искать различия будет накладно. Прийдется делать упрощения. Или ограничить поиск вглубину там до 10 уровня (приемлемой константы), или сравнивать группы таблиц.

Answer (score 0):

Вспомнил, что когда-то косвенно [похожий](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/679614/%D0%9F%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%83%D1%87%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-xpath%D1%8B?rq=1) вопрос я задавал:

Можно через CTE рекурсивно получить узлы, а потом регистрочувствительный JOIN'ом сравнивать:

```
DECLARE @xml XML = 
'<root>
<TableRow>
<field>45r</field>
</TableRow>
<TableRow>
<field>1</field>
<field2>1</field2>
</TableRow>
</root>';

WITH x ([Node], SubNode) AS
   (
      SELECT
         [Node]      = t.n.value('local-name(.)', 'nvarchar(max)'),
         [SubNode]   = t.n.query('*')
      FROM @xml.nodes('*') AS t(n)

      UNION ALL

      SELECT
         [Node]      = x.[Node] + N'/' + t.n.value('local-name(.)', 'nvarchar(max)'),
         [SubNode]   = t.n.query('*')
      FROM x
      CROSS APPLY x.SubNode.nodes('*') AS t(n)
   )
SELECT DISTINCT
   x.[Node]
FROM x;
```

Ну это пример неглубокого сравнения, так как атрибуты меня не интересуют.

Comment: *Допустим, есть XML A и XML B* @xml - это я так понял А, а где B?

Comment: @nick_n_a ну Б по сути получить таким же образов и переджойнить таблицы между собой.

Comment: 1. В вопросе не хватает... что отсутствуют атрибуты. Ваши еденицы потеряны. 2. В ответе не хватает А и Б (ну всё же вопрос и ответ как-то должны соответствовать) сейчас это скопированый ответ с ссылки. 3. Ещё накладывается условие что имена ветвей не могут повторятся. Если вы возьмете XML из кристала, или сохраните DataTable (http://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.datatable.writexml) или возьмете ADO-шную - то ваш метод даст кашу. Т.е. метод работает если допускается "упрощение". Но сам вариант обхода интересный.

Comment: @nick_n_a дополнил ответ тем, что это неглубокое сравнение.